# Distributable java files only work in dev machine

Tags: java, netbeans, deployment, jar

I created a Java application in NetBeans. That Java application contains a GUI and some external Jars.

In the dist folder I can see a Jar file and a folder called lib where are the jars I use in the project. If I execute the Jar file the application works as expected. If I change the name of the lib folder the application does not work (meaning that the Jar is using the correct files). But when I copy the dist folder to a different machine (with the same Java version) the application does not work as expected. The user interface is shown but the functionalities does not work (the functionalities are in the external Jars i mentioned in the beginning). Can anyone help?

EDIT:

I checked the class-path in the MANIFEST file and everything is ok.

Comment: Check that the Class-Path line in the MANIFEST.MF file is correct.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

The Class-Path is pointing to the files I have in the lib folder (that was created automatically by NetBeans). The only exception is that 2 jars are mentioned twice...is that the problem?

Comment: You need to copy the libs too.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Yes, I know. I copy the whole dist folder (main jar and lib folder which contains other jars that are in the class-path). But it does not work.